# React flip move not animating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation

Im trying to use `react-flip-move` but for some reason it does not animates.
Plz have a look at this.

https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KtqTYBCgNDqG0bDeDNA

```
 _handle = () => {
    if(x % 2 == 0){
      this.setState({ data: this.state.data.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)) });
    }else{
      this.setState({ data: this.state.data.sort((b, a) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)) });
    }
    x++;
  }
  render(){
    const {data} = this.state;
     return (
       <div>
         <button onClick={this._handle}>Sort</button>
       <FlipMove 
         duration={750}     
         easing="ease-out"
         enterAnimation = "accordianVertical"
         leaveAnimation = "accordianVertical"
         >
         {data.map((o,i) => (
           <li className="line" key={i} >
             {o.name}
           </li>
          ))}
       </FlipMove>       
       </div>
     );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `key` prop must be anything but index(0,1,2...n) .

In above example `key={o.name}` instead of `key={i}` works fine.